# Multiple PHP versions using phpenv, php-build and php-version

Tags: php, linux, apache

I'm on Arch Linux, trying to configure multiple PHP versions for testing my scripts.

I'm basing myself on these three tools:

- https://github.com/phpenv/phpenv
- https://github.com/CHH/php-build/
- http://wilmoore.com/php-version/

First I installed Apache and PHP (and their integration package) with `pacman`:

```
# pacman -S php apache php-apache
```

Next, I followed the instructions for installing the tools on the links, everything is working fine.

I manage to install two versions with `phpenv-install` from `php-build` tool. I got something like this:

```
-- ~
|---.phpenv
  |---lib
  |---versions
    |---5.5.1
    |---5.4.17
  |--- (some more folders)
```

On CLI environment everything is working fine, I can easily switch between the two versions with `php-version`:

```
$ php-version 5.5.1
$ php --version
PHP 5.5.1 (cli) (built: Aug  5 2013 22:54:47) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.2-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2013, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by Derick Rethans

$ php-version 5.4.17
$ php --version
PHP 5.4.17 (cli) (built: Aug  5 2013 23:19:44) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by Derick Rethans
```

Now the problem: integrate this with apache.

As I said in the beginning of this post, I also had to install PHP from Arch repositories, which coincidentally is on version 5.4.17. This installation is working fine with Apache.

On `php-env` readme there are these instructions:

> phpenv support dynamic switching for Apache apxs libraries and install
>   will build and install a libphp5.so shared library for Apache under
>   the versions libexec folder.
>
> By calling phpenv global to show or change the global PHP version a
>   link is created under ~/.phpenv/lib/libphp5.so for the appropriate
>   release build. This link can be used for Apache's LoadModule
>   php5_module directive and requires Apache to restart when changed.

The problem is that there is no file or symlink named `libphp5.so` in `lib` directory neither in the whole `.phpenv` folder, because

```
$ find ~/.phpenv -name libphp5.so
```

returns nothing.

Maybe because english is not my first language, I'm having some problem to intepret the second paragraph of the quote above.

Comment: Sorry to see your question has not been answered yet. Is there any progress you can share?

Comment: I ended giving up installing it on Arch. On debian-based distros it is possible to use phpbrew (https://github.com/c9s/phpbrew) that does not do what I intended first, but works fine. Basically, using it I can compile various versions of `libphp5.so` naming it like `libphp551.so`, `libphp5417.so` and switch betweeen versions using the command line tool. What I wanted was to associate a version to a specific port or something like that.

Comment: OK, not what I was hoping for, but thanks for the information!

Comment: What is the output of `locate libphp5.so`? Also, anything interesting in `~/.phpenv` and its subfolders?

Answer (score 1):

There is a package in the AUR for phpenv
https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/phpenv/

As well as packages for many different versions of PHP
https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/?O=0&C=0&SeB=nd&K=phpenv&outdated=&SB=n&SO=a&PP=50&do_Search=Go

First install phpenv:
yaourt phpenv

Then install the php versions you need, for example:
yaourt php53_29_env

Note: even with this though, you will likely have a problem. Checking the package build, it looks like it is missing the patch to disable PHP automatically being compiled with thread safe features when apache is running a thread safe mpm.   Not quite sure since on my systems, I want PHP to enable thread safe code so it will work for me.